# How do I get the sum of the values from the file input/output?

Tags: python, list, file, input, output

**py file =>**

```
x=''

m=open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/sales.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')

ss=[]

sum=0

while True :

    x=m.readline()

    if x=='':

        break

    print(x,end='')

for i in x :

    score=int(i)

    print(score)

sum=int(m[0]+m[1]+m[2]+m[3]+m[4]+m[5]+m[6]+m[7]+m[8]+m[9])

print(sum)

m.close()

inFp=open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/sales.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')

outFp=open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/summary.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')

while True :

    x=inFp.read(1)

    if not x :

        break

    outFp.write(x)

p=sum(int(m) for m in inFp.readlines())

outFp.write(str(int(p)))

print(outFp,end='')

print('total : 1221900')

print('avg : 122190')

inFp.close()

outFp.close()
```

**sales.txt file =>**

```
95000
125000
53000
26000
37400
230000
400000
79500
80300 
95700
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z-nYooUmPuNgQYf8NOlqr9XUVNOahv1X

The daily sales of the store were set at random.line2

Print out the daily turnover line by line.line5~9

Read this to store and print the average sales and total sales in another file called summary. line 22~23

In order to calculate, it must be called int, so `str(int(p))` was used. line 36

I didn't know how to calculate, so I wrote down the price by palm. line 39.40

I want to open the `sales.txt` file and print out the sales, and I want to convert these numbers into an integer and get the average and the total, and then I want to save all of these values in an empty file called `sample.txt` and print them out. Using file input/output.

Comment: Please: 1. Add exemplary data from sales.txt, 2. format the question correctly: all the code should be in the 'code' clause. 3. State your questions clearly and clearly. Please see the stack overflow post on that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please format your code properly within code blocks - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough all sales and add them to a varible. Something like that

```
sales = open("urfile.txt","r")
txt = sales.read()
saleslist = txt.split('\n')
sum = 0
for saleval in salelist:
   sum += int(saleval)
print(sum)
```